# Android NDK Environment Variables on Windows 7

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am currently trying to get the NDK up and running in Eclipse. I have read several tutorials, and found one that seems to make sense to me. However, it says:

```
Please make sure that you have set the environment variables like
JAVA_HOME -- Java Home Directory
NDK_HOME -- Android NDK Home Directory
Update Path Variable with JDK Bin folder
```

I am in my Environment Variables window, but am confused about what to do. I have no JAVA_HOME variable yet, so I need to create it, but with what value? The same goes with the NDK_HOME. I do have a PATH variable, which I edited earlier when I installed Cygwin.

By the way, this is the tutorial I am using: http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2010/05/how-to-addedit-environment-variables-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to generate an NDK development environment in Eclipse by using the information on the ARM site (http://ds.arm.com/ds-5-community-edition/).

There are some caveats to using the NDK. For instance, if you installed it in a path that has spaces embedded (for example C:\program files (x86)\Android) you'll run into problems.

Try to run the ndk-build.cmd command in a command prompt to see if you have any problems with your installation.

Comment: I don't think I need to download any additional software, I already have a C project with an Android.mk file. Do you think the ARM software is necessary? I don't think I need to do too much with the NDK, just get it up and running. Am I incorrect in thinking this?

Comment: well, in my case getting it to run with Eclipse just as-is was rather difficult (and I finally gave up on it). That's why I suggested the ARM environment (which actually works like it's described). Concerning the ndk path variables: have you been able to run the ndk-build.cmd command successfully in a vanilla command prompt?

Comment: No, I haven't. I downloaded Cygwin, and know basic Linux commands, but don't really know whats going on. I haven't looked at Cygwin since the 'ls' command wouldn't work, which I don't understand. I searched online to fix that and the solution was changing my Environment variables.

Comment: The thing is, though, in Windows you shouldn't need to install Cygwin to compile your code. Like you say, you need to add both the java and ndk-tools paths to your PATH environment variable. What response does the command window give you when you try typing in ndk-build.cmd? (BTW: If you want to continue this conversation we probably should open up a chat room or something of the sort)

Comment: "'ndk-build' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." I'm not sure how to start a chat here without the window popping up for us to start a chat.

Comment: I am sure its more likely that I am entering the build command incorrectly or am in the wrong folder as opposed to something being wrong with my system, but I really don't know.

Comment: Well, not according to my experience. Try to enter "ndk-build.cmd". But if it doesn't accept that command, it's because you: a.) didn't enter the path correctly or b.) don't have the tools installed. Like I said: maybe it's best if we try this via chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13109/discussion-between-juice-and-digcamara)