# Gradle build issue

Tags: android, android-ndk, gradle

I am trying to build android project with imported c-libraries and get next error.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Applications/Android Studio.app/ndk/ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/Users/eugene/KREF14001/app/build/ndk/debug/Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-19 NDK_OUT=/Users/eugene/KREF14001/app/build/ndk/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/Users/eugene/KREF14001/app/build/ndk/debug/lib APP_ABI=all
>     Error Code:
>       2
>     Output:
>       usage: dirname path
>       /Users/eugene/build/core/init.mk:471: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.

What does it mean? How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the NDK and not just the SDK?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded it, unzip and add it next line to local.properties ndk.dir=/Applications/Android Studio.app/ndk

Comment: please post your `Build.gradle`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211600/android-ndk-environment-variables-on-windows-7) that the NDK_HOME shouldn't contain any space in its path (even if it's \ escaped).

Answer (score 2):

This is the code i use to build using android-ndk from gradle. For this add ndk directory path in `gradle.properties` ie . add `ndkdir=/home/user/android-ndk-r9d` and put all jni files in a folder `native` in `src/main/` as you can see from code posted below. It will create jar with native libs which you can use normally as in `System.loadLibrary("library");`

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: '*.jar')
}

task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    commandLine "$ndkdir/ndk-build", "--directory", "$projectDir/src/main/native", '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
            "APP_PLATFORM=android-8",
            "APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=$projectDir/src/main/native/Android.mk",
            "NDK_OUT=$buildDir/native/obj",
            "NDK_APP_DST_DIR=$buildDir/native/libs/\$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)"
}

task nativeLibsToJar(type: Zip, description: 'create a jar with native libs') {
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
    baseName 'native-libs'
    extension 'jar'
    from fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native/libs", include: '**/*.so')
    into 'lib/'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn nativeLibsToJar
}

nativeLibsToJar.dependsOn 'ndkBuild'
```