# Android NDK Aborting stop

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am working on an application which uses some third party library for Image rendering. The same library runs on Eclipse but when I have imported that into AndroidStudio then it gives an NDK error.

```
Error:(199) *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
```

I did some R & D on Google and SO but that didn't solved my problem.

My Android.mk file,

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := gpuimage-library
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := yuv-decoder.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Please let me know, where I am wrong. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11212821

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your mk file and it worked well , so I think you are running your ndk-build just in jni dir, but it should be out of this dir.

Comment: One liners are not considered as answers..!!

Comment: Take a read of this, it will help improve your answers http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer