# Android opencv facedetection sample shows ndk abort error

Tags: android, opencv, github, android-ndk, java-native-interface

When I tried to Build **Opencv Face Detection sample** in android studio it shows Error:(198) *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.

The error location is in  /Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build/core/add-application.mk

Comment: Dos yuor Android installation path has some space in it? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/11212821/6309)

Comment: No my path doesn't have any space@VonC. I need to know the cause for the error is it in jni/android.mk or application.mk   or I need to change some thing in my Ndk.I dont know..